# getting this error while trying to run cube js

Tags: docker, cube.js

I'm getting this error while trying to run cube js with the default command in the getting started docs. I've started this in a folder and running it in docker.

```
Warning. There is no cube.js file. Continue with environment variables
 Cube Store (0.28.31) is assigned to 3030 port.
Warning. Option apiSecret is required in dev mode. Cube.js has generated it as e3b8c5a35fe378f4d481ada777e5f3c4
 Authentication checks are disabled in developer mode. Please use NODE_ENV=production to enable it.
 Dev environment available at http://localhost:4000
 Cube.js server (0.28.31) is listening on 4000
2021-09-03 15:06:01,512 INFO  [cubestore::http::status] <pid:17> Serving status probes at 0.0.0.0:3031
2021-09-03 15:06:01,515 INFO  [cubestore::metastore] <pid:17> Using existing metastore in /cube/conf/.cubestore/data/metastore
thread '
main
' panicked at '
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { message: "IO error: While fsync: a directory: Invalid argument" }
', /project/cubestore/src/metastore/mod.rs:1542:40
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Cube Store Start Error: undefined
```

Comment: Did you give cube privileges in your s.o ?

Comment: do you ever find a solution on it ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it’s corrupted metastore due to it was incorrectly shutdown for you locally. Could you please try to drop the .cubestore directory?

Comment: Thank you, this was 100% the correct action to take.  The exact error I had was:

Error: Unsupported db type: undefined
    at Function.driverDependencies (/cube/node_modules/@cubejs-backend/server-core/src/core/server.ts:887:11)
    at Function.lookupDriverClass (/cube/node_modules/@cubejs-backend/server-core/src/core/server.ts:872:45)
    at Object.dialectFactory (/cube/node_modules/@cubejs-backend/server-core/src/core/server.ts:410:49)
    at CompilerApi.dialectClass (/cube/node_modules/@cubejs-backend/server-core/src/core/server.ts:612:26)
(truncated(...